# Mathematical Recursive Equation for Time complexity of Linked list Search

Tags: algorithm, recursion, search, linked-list, time-complexity

How to formulate Mathematical equation for 'time complexity' of Searching an integer x in Linked List Using Recursion. Recursive Equation should obviously be in terms of n (where n=total number of elements in linked list). Below is the Java implementation of Recursive Search in Linked list.

```java
public static int search(Node head, int x) {
  if(head==null)
    return -1;
  else if(head.data==x)
     return 1;
  else {
     int res=search(head.next,x);
     if(res==-1)
        return -1;
     else 
        return res+1;
  }
}
```

I know that time complexity is obviously O(n) as it traverses every element to search in worst case but I want to derive the same from recursive equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define <sub>,</sub>  as the time complexity for performing the search, when the first node that has the targetted data is at position  (1-based) in a list that has  nodes. To get a useful value for  when there is no match, let's define  as the number of nodes in the longest prefix of the list that does not have the matching node, ... plus 1. So when there is no match, we will have  =  + 1.

Then:

<sub>1, 0</sub> represents the case of an empty list where there is (obviously) no such node.
      <sub>1,</sub>  represents the case where the head node has the targetted data

Then we have these equations:

<sub>1, 0</sub> = O(1)
      <sub>1,</sub>  = O(1)  when  > 0
      <sub>,</sub>  = O(1) + <sub>−1, −1</sub> when  > 1 and  > 0

The last equation reflects that the recursive call is made with `head.next`: that call deals with a list that is one node shorter, and so both the involved *size* () and matching *position* () are one less.

Which one of the base cases kicks in first depends on how  and  relate. If  =  + 1, then the first base case will kick in. In all other cases, the second base case will kick in.

The recurrence relation will thus resolve to:

<sub>,</sub>  = O()  when  <= 
      <sub>,</sub>  = O(1 + )  when  =  + 1

So in both cases:

<sub>,</sub>  = O()

...which in the worst case is O(1 + ) = O().